# Вывести изображения на всю страницу

Tags: html, изображения, css

Есть задача, вывести много изображений ( примерно `100x100` ) на всю страницу без отступов, есть варианты как это осуществить?

Comment: **пикчей** - а это что такое? )

Comment: Имеешь ввиду просто выводить картинки одну за одной, скажем по пять штук вряд?

Comment: пикчи в смысле (pictures) изобр.
Ну напрмер есть 100 картинок 100x100, их нужно вывести одну за одной без отступов, по всей ширине и высоте, и желательно фиксировано

Comment: Сколько картинок должно идти в ряд? Или все 100?

Comment: я так понял, сколько влезет на странице, остальные переносить?

Comment: @Хэшкод, предлагаю забанить @foozzi за неуважительное отношение к участникам сообщества

Comment: @danpetruk, хочу поделиться одним правилом, которого придерживаюсь уже много лет: "Не реагируй на раздражитель зеркально!" Другими словами, если, к примеру, в подворотне на вас лает шавка, вы же будете уподобляться ей, становиться на четвереньки и тявкать в ответ? (*Вопрос риторический*) Делите проблему на двадцать;)

Answer (score 2):

вот так, что-ли?

```
img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@foozzi](/users/6259/foozzi), не помешало бы несколько уточнений. Если вам без разницы, что нижний ряд может остаться полупустым, если не нужно проверять соотношение сторон изображений (*они же "пикчи"*) и не имеет значения: в большую сторону подгонять изображения или меньшую, то [всё предельно просто](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7SWKf/).

Но если все-таки есть некоторые нюансы, которые вам важны, то ждем-с уточнений.

Comment: соотношение сторон изображений одниковы - 100x75
требуется вывести то кол. изображений, сколько влезит в разрешение монитора компьютера пользователя, и все это фиксировано, то есть без прокрутки, все изобр. уже обрезаны под размер

Comment: Все трабыл решил кроме одной, сделал все выводимые картинки фиксированными, при уменьшении окна браузера, они переносятся на другую строку, как убрать переносы?

Comment: вот пример - http://tp-test.p.ht/1/index2.php
если уменьшить ширину страницы, то можно увидеть, большие отступы, а потом перенос картинки

Comment: @foozzi, вы не "решили траблы", как вы сказали. Поставленная вами задача, не решается только с помощью css и варианта, предложенного @danpetruk (***inline-block** - это хорошо, но не ваш случай*).

Answer (score 2):

```
img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display:inline-block; /*будет переносить на новые строки*/
    margin:0;
}
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Xqmfy/)

**UPDATE1** может можно обойтись [этим](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-image)?

Comment: спасибо, то что надо, но теперь нужно сделать все фиксированно, то есть например на экране 800x600 все будет с прокруткой, а у меня на 1600x900 будет норм, как сделать что бы при малом разрешении экрана не было прокрутки, а просто выводилось столько изобр. сколько влезет на экран?

Comment: @fozzi т.е. вы хотите, чтобы на 800х600 влезало меньше изображений?

Comment: да, что бы не было скролинга

Comment: @foozzi добавьте к body:  overflow:hidden;

Comment: добавил, все равно есть скролинг.
И еще один вопрос, по сентру экрана есть к примеру одна большая картинка, трубется что бы те маленькие которые выводятся, не опускали большую к низу, а просто выводились по бокам

Comment: @foozzi http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=html+%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F+%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&from=os&clid=1836588&lr=213 :)

Comment: пиши по делу, не знаешь, оф с топика

Comment: Я то знаю, а вот вы - нет. А это базовые знания, которые должны знать даже новички. От сюда и моя ссылка

Comment: @danpetruk, еще выкаешь ушлепану...

Comment: @Bars граммар наци за тобой выехали, чапа

Comment: в вашем случае лучше уж вместо margin: 0; поставить vertical-align: top;